# XMLHttpRequest onprogress not firing on async = false

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, form-data

When sending a XMLHttpRequest with async = false, the xhr.upload.onprogress events is never fired doing file upload.

Source:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("name", files[i].name);
form.append("size", files[i].size);
form.append("type", files[i].type);
form.append("image", files[i]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){
    alert("Progress event fired!");
    if (evt.lengthComputable) 
    {
        var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100; 
        console.log(percentComplete); 
    } 
};

xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(files[i].name + " uploaded!");
};

xhr.open("post", "/images/upload", false);
xhr.send(form);
```

I have tested this in both Firefox and Chrome.

I have no idea if i missed some documentation but could not find anything that indicated that the xhr.upload.onprogress event is not fired when async = false?.

If i change the request to run with async = true it´s fired.

Comment: In [section 4.5.6 of the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/), you can read what the spec says about progress events.

Comment: The first rule about synchronous HTTP requests: You do not use them. Ever. *Ever.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you should **not** use synchronous request, especially in file uploads, that may take some time.

Using sync requests, you **block thread execution** until everything is done (the file is uploaded), and even if the `onprogress` event would've been fired, you could not update any progress bars because the UI and all other processing (but the file upload) would be blocked.

Those events were created so that you could handle asynchronous requests.

If you read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), you'll see that synchronous requests have been deprecated in some browser versions.